# jquery-ui dialog doesn't size correctly when content has white-space wrapping disabled

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, word-wrap

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
    Some text containing spaces which could be wrapped.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("div").dialog();
    });
</script>
```

When this dialog opens, the size is too narrow to display the unwrapped contents.

How can I ensure the dialog is wide enough without setting an arbitrary width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got that right, adding `width:auto` as a dialog option  is enough

```
$("div").dialog({
  width:'auto'
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/rLQjjL

Comment: Looking at the code of ui.dialog's `_size` function, this does cause a strange comparison at `if ( options.minWidth > options.width ) {` but no errors :-)